# PL/SQL : Initialize variable value before Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to initialize variable value before Cursor declaration ?

My requirement is to pass value to Cursor which is obtained by invoking another function.

```
Function SomeFunction(Param1, Param2) Is

SomeParam := fn_findSomeParamValue(Param1,Param2); //This is giving compilation error

Cursor C1 is
select * from SomeTable where SomeColumn = SomeParam;
```

Comment: *What* compilation error is it giving? Have you declared the `SomeParam` variable? Show us a full example, not a couple of random lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as :

```
Function SomeFunction(Param1, Param2) Is

Cursor C1(someparam <datatype>) is
select * from SomeTable where SomeColumn = SomeParam;

someparam <datatype>;

begin

SomeParam := fn_findSomeParamValue(Param1,Param2); //This is giving compilation error

--Pass it as parameter to cursor
Open C1(someparam);

...
...
end;
```